# Puppeteer won't return an HTML tag in headless mode but will when it is not in headless mode - why is this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've recently began experimenting with Puppeteer in JavaScript for webscraping and noticed that when I run my code with a headless Puppeteer instance, it will not return the tag that I am looking for but will instead return `[]`.  However, when headless mode is turned off, the code returns the tag just fine.   The tag that it returns is

```
[ ElementHandle {
    _context:
     ExecutionContext { _client: [CDPSession], _world: [DOMWorld], _contextId: 3 },
    _client:
     CDPSession {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 27,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       _callbacks: Map {},
       _connection: [Connection],
       _targetType: 'page',
       _sessionId: '6950CA7711045DA500204C2EFDAFC5B3' },
    _remoteObject:
     { type: 'object',
       subtype: 'node',
       className: 'HTMLHeadingElement',
       description: 'h1',
       objectId: '{"injectedScriptId":3,"id":3}' },
    _disposed: false,
    _page:
     Page {
       _events: {},
       _eventsCount: 0,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       _closed: false,
       _client: [CDPSession],
       _target: [Target],
       _keyboard: [Keyboard],
       _mouse: [Mouse],
       _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
       _touchscreen: [Touchscreen],
       _accessibility: [Accessibility],
       _networkManager: [NetworkManager],
       _frameManager: [FrameManager],
       _emulationManager: [EmulationManager],
       _tracing: [Tracing],
       _pageBindings: Map {},
       _ignoreHTTPSErrors: false,
       _coverage: [Coverage],
       _javascriptEnabled: true,
       _viewport: [Object],
       _screenshotTaskQueue: [TaskQueue],
       _workers: Map {} },
    _frameManager:
     FrameManager {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 3,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       _client: [CDPSession],
       _page: [Page],
       _networkManager: [NetworkManager],
       _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
       _frames: [Map],
       _contextIdToContext: [Map],
       _isolatedWorlds: [Set],
       _mainFrame: [Frame] } } ]
```

I have tried using `await page.goto(url, {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});` to make the program wait until the page is fully loaded before returning the tag but again no luck.  Here is my dysfunctional code:

```
const initializeBrowserTask = async (proxy) => {
  console.log("Initializing browser task...");
  if (proxy == '') {
    console.log('No proxy.')
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    return browser;
  } else {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      'args': ['--proxy-server=`${proxy}`']
    });
    console.log("Proxy: `${proxy}`")
    return browser;
  };

}

const browserTask = async (proxy, url) => {
  const browser = await initializeBrowserTask(proxy);
  let check = 0
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  console.log('Running...')
  await page.goto(url);
  console.log("Arrived at URL!")
  let status = await page.$x('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/h1');
  console.log(status)


};

browserTask('', 'http://adidas.com/yeezy')
```

I did remove the `{"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"}` as mentioned before as it did not solve the issue.  For some reason, this code will work when the browser is not headless but will return `[]` when it is.  Why is this problem occurring and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out what was going wrong with my code.  Apparently, the site I was trying to scrape (adidas.com) filters out requests based off of headers.  What I didn't realize is that in headless mode, I was actually arriving at Adidas's 403 Access Denied page which is why the tag I wanted to find was non-existent.  I guess headless puppeteer is just another way of sending HTTP requests while non-headless is more of an actual webdriver, which is why the non-headless mode was not blocked by Adidas.

To fix the headless mode and add the appropriate headers, I used this line of code before the `page.goto(url);' line:

`await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36');`

It turns out all I was missing were the headers to trick the Adidas site into not blocking me.